# How to run multiple pages on one gcloud app

Tags: php, gcloud

I have a php page (login.php) that simply takes a user's username and password. They are then suppose to be redirected to another php page (main.php) if the details are correct (which they are). But when the redirect is attempted I just land back on login.php even though the URL at the top states it's on main.php

I figure the issue is in my app.yaml file as I suspect it is only uploading the login.php but I can't find anything on the internet suggesting how to upload multiple files or when I do try something I can't deploy the app.

**app.yaml file:**

```
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: www/login.php
```

**login.php:**

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...');
include_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;

$datastore = new DatastoreClient(['...' => $projectId]);

if(isset($_POST["userId"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
  $key = $datastore->key(user, $_POST["userId"]);
  $entity = $datastore->lookup($key);
  if(!is_null($entity)){
    header("Location: https://tenacious-post-271702.appspot.com/main.php");
    exit;
  }
  else{
    echo "User id or password is invalid";
  }
}
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Please enter your details</h3>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="userId" value="" placeholder="User Id">
      <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.php:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Main</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Main Page</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please confirm me if in your login.php file, the form action is correct? I see it pointing to login.php which may indicate why even though you are pressing on the redirect button, you are landing in the same page. Try changing it with main.php.  Thank you!

Comment: While this would work, I had to do some work on the data given on login.php which could have resulted in staying on login.php anyways due to incorrect usernames or passwords. So either way I would have had to use a redirect somewhere. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So after lots of trial and error and researching I manage to fix the problem. You have to include every page in the app.yaml file that you wish to deploy with your app, which I thought so, but wasn't sure how exactly to do this in the file. So you app.yaml should include a url and script attribute for every php page you have. For example: I have 4 pages for my site and therefore:

**app.yaml**

```
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: www/login.php

- url: /main.php
  script: www/main.php

- url: /name.php
  script: www/name.php

- url: /password.php
  script: www/password.php

- url: /login.php
  script: www/login.php
```